# Deserialize JSON Array With Integer Index

Tags: json

I am trying to avoid having to do a JSON deserialized untyped, but not sure if I can...
I get back a response of contact data from a third party that looks something like this:

```
{"data": {
"1500":{"id":"1500","last_name":"Test1"},
"298":{"id":"298","last_name":"Test2"}
},
"status_code":200}
```

So if you use JSONtoApex, you get a class like this:

```
public class jContactsDemo {

    public class Data {
        public 1500 1500;
        public 1500 298;
    }

    public class 1500 {
        public String id;
        public String last_name;
    }

    public Data data;
    public Integer status_code;
```

Which makes sense - but of course, 1500 and 298 are both contacts with the same structure - so is there some way I am not thinking of to just let me use JSON.deserialize into a Apex Class that can recognize that each entry in the array is the same type?

I had tried to use an initial conversion using JSON.deserializeUntyped, and then loop through results of Map, convert to String, and deserialize each record one at a time:

```
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);

 for (String s: m.keyset()){
     Map<String, Object> mData = (Map<String, Object>)m.get('data');
     for (String s2: mData.keyset()){
         String sJSON = String.ValueOf(mData.get(s2));
        system.debug(sJSON);
     }   
}
```

But when I look at the value I get out of the Map, all the double quotes have been removed, which throws a different error...

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): was
>   expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:3]

Comment: Hi, have you tried my method? I've tested and verified that you can indeed deserialise into the object of your choice, provided you do a little fiddling beforehand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are going to laugh at this, but it turns out that **REENCODING** as JSON at each step gets you your quoted values. Strange but true!! Try this:

```
String jsonData = '{"data": {"1500":{"id":"1500","last_name":"Test1"},"298":{"id":"298","last_name":"Test2"}},"status_code":200}';

//get top level map
Map<String,Object> jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonData);

//extract data as JSON
String jsonSubset = JSON.serialize(jsonMap.get('data'));

//re-encode as a Map
Map<String,Object> jsonSubsetMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonSubset);

MyContact[] contacts = new MyContact[]{};
for (Object obj : jsonSubsetMap.values()){
    //re-encode as json, again!
    String jsonObj = JSON.serialize(obj);
    //deserialize that b@#$ard!!
    MyContact contact = (EBTestDeleteMe.MyContact)JSON.deserialize(jsonObj, MyContact.class);
    contacts.add(contact);
}

System.debug(contacts);
```

This outputs:

```
DEBUG|(MyContact:[id=298, last_name=Test2], MyContact:[id=1500, last_name=Test1])
```

This assumes you have a class called `MyContact` that looks like this:

```
public class MyContact {
    public String id;
    public String last_name;
}
```

Comment: That is genius...though I feel like I need to take a shower after so much hackery... :)

Comment: Hahah. Yes, it is a bit hackish :)

Comment: like that code comment statement b@#$ard!!!

Comment: @CaspNZ This is called nailed it ....

Comment: Haha, I was pretty pleased with the outcome too... That comment wouldn't have made to production code ;)

Comment: Wow ! Awesome Caspar Harmer

Answer (score 1):

Good question and very easy to get confused with format you have. [As per JSON Syntax](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/why-should-i-use-json-over-xml/), format should be `Key : Value`.

Eventhough `1500` and `298` in your case has same structure but it has different key names. Thats why Salesforce or any other programming language will consider it as different node.

To answer your question - Did you tried something like this ?

```
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
List<Object> lstNode = (List<Object>) m.get('1500');
```

If not, Can you please post sample code.

Comment: Thing is, I won't know the Ids until I get back the response - so see sample above - I have to loop through the results of the 'data' object in the initial map to get each entry I need - but when I use that syntax, it seems to strip my "" from the JSON, and I can't deserialize it?

Comment: You can, check my answer out!