# System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set while deseriliasing json Payload

Tags: community, rest-api, json, rest, deserialize

```
> I have resolved the issue updating answer for my own question thanks for response Stack-exchange great help everytime :
> 
> >     1.Malformed JSON: Expected '[' 
> >     Answer:Used remove string method to remove root from response it worked.
> >     2.error 'System.JSONException: For input string: "".
> >     Answer:My json response has got parameter which is returning String and unfortunately Json2apex generated that element as integer
> > not sure why...I rectified that it is working perfect.
> 
> Hope it helps
```

This is Json Response:

```
 {"root":[{"across_na_flag":0,"added_by_date":"\/Date(1374552000000-0400)\/","added_by_user_name":611,"addr1":"Hartford Forklift Service","addr2":"50 Northern Ave","addr3":"Auburn, ME 04210-6125","addr4":" ","addr5":" ","addr6":" ","addr_sort1":"EQPDLR","addr_sort2":"WHSALE","addr_sort3":"NONSNA","address_name":"Hartford Forklift Service","address_type":0,"affiliated_cust_code":"","aging_limit_bracket":4,"alt_location_code":"1JOL","attention_email":"","attention_name":"Accounts Payable","attention_phone":2072124769,"bal_fwd_flag":0,"check_aging_limit":1,"check_credit_limit":1,"check_display_comment":"","check_extendedname_flag":0,"city":"Auburn","consolidated_invoices":0,"contact_email":"","contact_name":"Carl","contact_phone":2072124769,"country":"US","country_code":"US","credit_limit":5000,"cust_po_allow_dup":0,"cust_po_req":0,"customer_code":"CS031191","date_opened":735072,"db_credit_rating":" ","db_date":0,"db_num":" ","ddid":"","delivery_days":"","dest_zone_code":"North","dunn_message_code":"","dunning_group_id":"","entry_ordered_by":0,"extended_name":"","fin_chg_code":"N\/A","fob_code":"ORIGIN","forwarder_code":"","freight_code":"","freight_to_code":"","ftp":"","guid":"","inv_comment_code":"","invoice_copies":1,"iv_substitution":0,"late_chg_type":2,"limit_by_home":0,"location_code":"MAN","modified_by_date":"\/Date(1446818192743-0500)\/","modified_by_user_name":818,"nat_cur_code":"USD","note":"","one_cur_cust":1,"payer_soldto_rel_code":"        ","payment_code":"CHK-3RD","phone_1":2072124769,"phone_2":"","postal_code":"04210-6125","posting_code":"3RDBOS","price_code":"CNCMHCD","price_level":1,"print_stmt_flag":1,"rate_type_home":"BUY","rate_type_oper":"BUY","remit_code":"LOCKBOX","resale_num":"EXEMPT","route_code":"","route_no":0,"salesperson_code":"CORPORAT","ship_complete_flag":0,"ship_to_code":"","ship_to_history":0,"ship_via_code":"BESTWAY","short_name":"Hartford F","so_priority_code":" ","special_instr":"","state":"ME","status_type":1,"stmt_comment_code":"","stmt_cycle_code":"MNTHLYST","tax_code":"AVATAX","tax_exempt_cust_type":0,"tax_id_num":"","terms_code":"NET30","territory_code":2100,"timestamp":[0,0,0,0,156,175,60,241],"tlx_twx":"","trade_disc_percent":0,"url":"","valid_payer_flag":1,"valid_shipto_flag":1,"valid_soldto_flag":1,"vendor_code":"","writeoff_code":"OSBOS"}]}
```

I am trying to deserialize the Payload which is in array form facing this error'System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set'

```
 String jsonstring={"root":[{"across_na_flag":0,"added_by_date":"\/Date(1374552000000-0400)\/",,"addr6":" "},{........}]}
 list<Item> is my wrapper class class:
 list<Item> accountArray = (list<Item>)JSON.deserialize(jsonstring, Item[].class);
```

I understand it is the issue of Root here then I tried this way:

```
Map<String,Object> jsonMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonstring);
String jsonSubset = JSON.serialize(jsonMap.get('root'));
list<Item> accountArray = (list<Item>)JSON.deserialize(jsonstring, Item[].class);
```

I got this error 'System.JSONException: For input string: "" at [line:1, column:1356]';

I have to iterate on the response in this way to insert records:

```
for (Item a:accountArray){
 if(a.customer_code!=refAccount.Customer_ID__c)
               {

                 processResponse(a);                    
  }
```

Wrapper class:

```
public class  Item {

    public List<Account> root;
    public Integer across_na_flag;
    public String added_by_date;   
    public String addr6;  


    }
```

Comment: It is perfect check on jsonlint.com

Comment: Problem is that when you do JSON.deserializeUntyped first time, that automatically decode all the special characters (as ", \ etc), so thats why when you try to deserialize it second time - that throw you exception. I would recommend you to create one more wrapper class via json2apex or by yourself to be able to parse it directly from initial JSON like **class MainWrapper{ List<Item> root; }**

Comment: Thanks for reply...I did that the wrapper which I have is from json2apex.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75622/deserialize-json-array-with-integer-index)

I had the same issue, and Caspar Harmer suggested I re-encode the json at each stage and crazy as it sounds, it worked great.