# Error desearlizing JSON of type BatchInfo - Bulk API

Tags: apex, json, rest, bulk-api, serialization

I am trying to get the status,# record processed etc details by hitting the bulk API endpoint - `/services/async/39.0/job/75037000003BXtw/batch`

In response I got the below JSON structure:

```
{"batchInfo":[{"apexProcessingTime":1993,"apiActiveProcessingTime":4765,"createdDate":"2017-07-26T23:51:29.000+0000","id":"751370000046EakAAE","jobId":"75037000003BXtwAAG","numberRecordsFailed":0,"numberRecordsProcessed":500,"state":"Completed","stateMessage":null,"systemModstamp":"2017-07-26T23:51:37.000+0000","totalProcessingTime":5447}]}
```

I used JSONtoApex tool to generate the required Class to parse the JSON:

```
public class BatchInfo {
    public Integer apexProcessingTime;
    public Integer apiActiveProcessingTime;
    public String createdDate;
    public String id;
    public String jobId;
    public Integer numberRecordsFailed;
    public Integer numberRecordsProcessed;
    public String state;
    public Object stateMessage;
    public String systemModstamp;
    public Integer totalProcessingTime;
}
```

As usual I use the below code to desearialize the JSON file:

```
List<BatchInfo> respJson =(List<BatchInfo>)JSON.deserialize(res2.getbody() , List<BatchInfo>.class);
```

I get an error saying - `System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set`

On doing some research I found a link which could resolve this issue - [Deserialize JSON Array With Integer Index](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75622/deserialize-json-array-with-integer-index) , but I get some other error now when I try to desearlize using the code in the link:

```
Map<String,Object> jsonMap = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res2.getbody());
String jsonSubset = JSON.serialize(jsonMap.get('batchInfo'));
system.debug('JsonSubset======>' + jsonSubset); // [{"totalProcessingTime":5447,"systemModstamp":"2017-07-26T23:51:37.000+0000","stateMessage":null,"state":"Completed","numberRecordsProcessed":500,"numberRecordsFailed":0,"jobId":"75037000003BXtwAAG","id":"751370000046EakAAE","createdDate":"2017-07-26T23:51:29.000+0000","apiActiveProcessingTime":4765,"apexProcessingTime":1993}]
Map<String,Object> jsonSubsetMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonSubset); // get below error at this line
```

Error - `System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to Map<String,ANY>`

Any suggestion? or Answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't quite have the right structure. You need an outer wrapper as well.

```
public class BulkApiResponse
{
    public List<BatchInfo> batchInfo;
}
```

Now you can deserialize the structure:

```
BulkApiResponse response = (BulkApiResponse)JSON.deserialize(payload, BulkApiResponse.class);
```

Note that you can *always* tell whether or not you can deserialize into a collection by whether or not the payload starts with a square bracket (`[`). If it starts with a curly bracket (`{`), you need to use a `Map` or `Object` as the type to deserialize into.

Comment: Cool. I guess the link I mentioned in my question is a different problem. My JSON only had primitive types in it when I converted it into Apex class.

Comment: @SfdcBat It looks like you passed in just the inner part of the list to JSON2Apex.

Comment: I missed this part completely from jsontoapex class -  `public class JSON2Apex {
  public List<BatchInfo> batchInfo;
 }` Thanks for pointing this out.